# Printf in C count X coord

Tags: c, windows, printf, windows-console

I am working on simple program in C where I must add and edit lines. The problem is when I edit line, I must to know a X coord to color edited Var with red. If I print a all selected line with green i use:

```
if(PROGRAM[0][i] == 3) {            
       cprintf("if Var%d > Var%d %d",PROGRAM[1][i],PROGRAM[2][i],PROGRAM[3][i]); 
}
```

which counts the x Coord of Var automatically(in printf function). Then I need to color red just Var2. How easy to obtain X coord of Var2? (the Var can have multipple digits, "Var10" as example)

EDIT:
My idea was to use the same printf as in green printing, just somehow to ignore the rest of text around Var2.

[image: automaticaly]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but I'd say that you don't need to know any coordinate, just call `cprintf()` more than once. Like `cprintf("if Var%d > ",PROGRAM[1][i]); cprintf("Var%d",PROGRAM[2][i]); cprintf(" %d",PROGRAM[3][i]);`

Comment: Yes, before I use printf() I set coordinations of beginning of "if...." with gotoxy(x,y). Thats all I need.

Comment: Of course if it is possible, I would like to avoid calculation of Var2 coord and so.

Comment: Oh, now I realize what do you mean, Thank you, I forgott the printf will increases the X coord after it is processed.

Comment: If you have found the solution to your issue, I'd suggest you answer your own question (and accept the answer). It lets other users know that the issue is solved :)